# Can't get page slider to work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mobile, scroll

So I've been using this slider I found on codepen. It's worked great but I can't seem to figure out how to make the pages slide when you're on a mobile phone. You can make the pages slide using your mouse scroll or your key arrows but nothing for touch device?

```
<p>See the code <a href="https://codepen.io/WispProxy/pen/EyLWKg/">Gray & White - Skewed Slider with Scrolling</a> by Victor Belozyorov</p>
```

Comment: So build the touch events? Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing a **specific** problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: You need to add touch events if the slider you are using does not already include them.

Comment: so far I've added     touchStartHandler = function touchStartHandler() {
    if (currentPage === countOfPages) {
      return;
    }

    currentPage++;
    _switchPages();
    
  };                                                                                                               Which has left me move the slider down, but when I try to reverse it so I can move back up it I can't get the first slider to scroll without holding it down but then it returns to slide1.